# Data not persisted with Room Persistence Library while upgrading Database Version

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

When I upgrade my Database from Version 1 to Version 2 and insert new data then all old data stored in Version 1 of database were deleted and I can see only newly inserted data in database.

Any idea how to persist data while upgrading database with Room Library?

Comment: You likely need to look at your **`onUpgrade`** method in the DBHelper, this gets called when you increment the DB version. Many people appear to code Dropping tables followed by a call to **`onCreate`** (copied from tutorials) e.g. `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);`, I suspect you might have something similar coded.

Comment: I am not using traditional DBHelper. I am using Room Persistence Library check this link **https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html**

Comment: In this case you may not have provided a suitable migration class as _Caution: If you don't provide the necessary migrations, Room rebuilds the database instead, which means you'll lose all of your data in the database._ appears to reflect the issue (quote from the link you provided in the **Database migration** section).

Comment: There's a section how to provide migration functions for room in your link: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#db-migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution from the same link. And when the migration class is not provided then Room Library deletes whole Database with data on onUpgrade() and create Database again.

It is compulsory to provide **Migration class** if you want to persist data on onUpgrade()